# How do I get past this error for my Yelp extractor?

Tags: java, web-scraping, exception, jsoup

I originally compiled this before I made a few changes to allow the me to specify searches and location. I can take it out if need be, but I'd rather not. Here's what I got:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class YelpScrapper
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String description;
        String location;
        int pages;
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter a description: ");
        description = keyboard.nextLine();
        
        System.out.print("Enter a location: ");
        location = keyboard.nextLine();
        
        System.out.print("How many pages should we scan? ");
        pages = keyboard.nextInt();
        
        String descString = "find_desc=" + description.replace(' ', '+') + "&";
        String locString = "find_loc=" + location.replace(' ', '+') + "&";
        int number = (pages * 10) - 10;
        
        String url = "https://www.yelp.com/search?" + descString + locString + "start=" + number;
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> address = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> phone = new ArrayList<String>();
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    
        Elements nameElements = document.select(".indexed-biz-name span");
        Elements addressElements = document.select(".secondary-attributes address");
        Elements phoneElements = document.select(".biz-phone");
        
        for (Element element : nameElements)
        {
            names.add(element.text());
        }
        
        for (Element element : addressElements)
        {
            address.add(element.text());
        }
        
        for (Element element : phoneElements)
        {
            phone.add(element.text());
        }
        
        for (int index = 0 ; index <= number ; index++)
        {
            System.out.println("\nLead " + index);
            System.out.println("Company Name: " + names.get(index));
            System.out.println("Address: " + address.get(index));
            System.out.println("Phone Number: " + phone.get(index));
        }
        
        //for (String name : names)
        //{
           // System.out.println(name);
        //}
        
        //System.out.println("\n");
        
        //for (String add : address)
        //{
            //System.out.println(add);
        //}
        
        //for (String pho : phone)
        //{
            //System.out.println(pho);
        //}
    }
}
```

The error I am receiving from BlueJ java.net.SocketTimeoutException; Read timed out(in java.net.SocketInputStream)

Should I be throwing another exception?

Comment: Can you print the URL after concatenating and see if you can access the page in a browser.  Might be some issue with the URL

Comment: actually i just threw an Exception and it apparently runs now. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setting a timeout might help?

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10000).get();
```